# Sudden permissions denied for service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I Have a ServiceAccount that has permissions to do all sort of things on my GCP project, and a Jenkins pipeline that runs on nightly basis and shutdown one of my GKE environments.
Few days ago i've started noticing random failures on fetching credentials for the cluster, while running the same pipeline again works.

i have the following block of code:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=****
gcloud container clusters get-credentials integration-cluster --zone europe-west1-c --project integration-project
```

the thing is, on nights it failed i see the following error:

```
00:00:45  Activated service account credentials for: [jenkins-user@integration-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
00:00:46  Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
00:00:46  ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/integration-project/zones/europe-west1-c/clusters/integration-cluster".
```

like the serviceAccount if lack of permissions on the project, but nothing has changed and rerun works.

what can be the reason for this?
it looks like a bug but....where? i'm using now Google Cloud SDK 319.0.0.

10x

Comment: Did you figure it out? What was the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Error message `message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s)` means that your service account doesn't have `container.clusters.get` permission.

Accordingly to the documentation [Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) section [Kubernetes Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles) roles `roles/container.clusterViewer` and `roles/container.clusterAdmin` contain this permission.

**To solve this issue** you can grant to your service account role that contains permission `container.clusters.get`. The least-privileged IAM role that provides this permission is `roles/container.clusterViewer`.  For more details please have a look at the documentation [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) section [Granting access to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#granting_access_to_service_accounts).

**If your service account has all the required permissions** you can file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or reach [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Comment: @user14242404 - Does this answer resolve your issue? If so, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).